# executar funçao que está dentro de um extract JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando usar funçoes que estao dentro de um export, por exemplo a `BigInteger`, aliás todas estao:

http://travistidwell.com/jsencrypt/bin/jsencrypt.js

mas preciso usa-las em outro arquivo para nao precisar repetir, é possivel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não vai ser possível aceder a todas as funções internas, mas podes aceder ao que é exportado desse módulo.

**Explicação:** Quando tens uma estrutura do tipo:

```
(function (exports) {
    function a() {
        alert('oi');
    }
})(escopo);
```

essa função `a` está dentro de um escopo que não permite ser acessível para fora. Isso usa-se muito para limitar o escopo das funções e não poluir o espaço global com nomes de variáveis.

Repara que nesse ficheiro que referiste elle acaba com:

```
exports.JSEncrypt = JSEncrypt;
})(JSEncryptExports);
```

ou seja, ele exporta para o objeto/variável que fôr passado a `JSEncryptExports`.

Portanto algumas funções nunca terás acesso, mas os métodos que são espostos podes encontrar em `JSEncryptExports`. E dessa maneira podes reaproveitar o código.

É commum usar-se assim quando se quer exportar para o espaço global:

```
(function(global){
     // código A aqui...
     global.meuModulo = function(a, b, c){
         // código que tem acesso aos métodos defenidos no "código A"
     }
})(typeof exports != 'undefined' ? exports : window);
```

Dessa maneira funciona tanto em NodeJS como no Browser.

Comment: nao tem como eu adaptar este codigo para funcionar como eu quero? Tipo remover tudo do escopo ou passar a variavel para eu usar por fora

Comment: @user3163662 podes juntar na ultima linha antes de `exports.JSEncrypt = JSEncrypt;` uma maneira de exportar essa função -> `exports.BigInteger = BigInteger;` e depois usar `JSEncryptExports.BigInteger` fora desse módulo.

Comment: +1 É por isso que eu odeio encapsulamento, o pessoal abusa muito... Tudo bem esconder detalhes internos de uma implementação, mas pra que esconder uma biblioteca inteira?!

Comment: @mgibsonbr é muito ruim, veja eu estou usando esta biblioteca e outra que usam AS MESMAS FUNCOES dela mas nao posso usar por causa desse encapsulamento, ai fica esse amuntuado de codigo desnecessario, odeio.. Obrigado Sergio!

Comment: @mgibsonbr Parece ter sido malfeito mesmo. A indentação indica que a IIFE e o exports foram adicionados posteriormente, às pressas. O certo seria declarar as dependências (num package.json, no formato da npm) e usar requires, em vez de encapsular bibliotecas externas.